# Trouble connecting the cassandra database via remote access through JAVA

Tags: cassandra, rpc

I have started the Cassandra server, before that I have changed "rpc_address" in cassandra.yaml.I can access the cassandra from the same machine but I could not access the cassandra from remote machine through Java application using Hector Client. Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough info in your description. 1) Is your router configured to allow traffic for cassandra in/out and does it forward the necessary ports to the cassandra machine. 2) Are any firewalls on the machine configured to allow cassandra traffic in/out ? Start by checking if you can ping the machine, then check if port 9160 is open, then try switching any/all firewalls just as a test to see if you can then access cassandra.

Comment: I could ping the machine. But I could not access the machine using telnet in windows. The servers is linux machine. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Firewall is blocking off the telnet port and probably the rest of the ports cassandra needs. You need to add an exception telling the firewall to open port 9160 (the client port). 9160 is the only port you really need to have open unless you want remote jmx management etc.

Comment: My server is running on linux machine, Where am I need to open port 9160 ? In my client windows or server linux ?

Comment: In the linux server ofc. You want `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9160 --syn -j ACCEPT` and then to save the state of the firewall after a reboot you use `service iptables save` [Source](http://www.tixati.com/optimize/open-ports-linux.html)

Comment: I ran the commands in the linux server and restarted the server. How can I verify it is update correctly ?

Comment: Start cassandra and try accessing it :D

Comment: I could access the database server remotely. Thanks man. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could ping the machine. But I could not access the machine using telnet in windows. The servers is linux machine. Do you have any idea ?

Your firewall is blocking off the telnet port and probably the rest of the ports cassandra needs. You need to add an exception telling the firewall to open port 9160 (the client port). 9160 is the only port you really need to have open unless you want remote jmx management etc.

To add an exception to your linux firewall:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9160 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

And if you want to save the state:

```
service iptables save
```